# How to show image in relation search resource in laravel nova

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

i make field with relation

```
BelongsTo::make
```

and want add for search title image, the link to the image is stored in the resource field as url

I tried to make an img tag, but the title escapes the html code

```
    public function title()
{
    return "$this->name <img src='/open_emoji/lite_colored/$this->name.png'>";
}
```

https://nova.laravel.com/docs/4.0/resources/relationships.html#searchable-relations
the documentation shows a picture that this is possible and that's it!

there is also a certain avatar field, but which is just as terribly documented and does not explain how to work with relationships.

Can someone please explain how to do this? i am use nova 4

Comment: maybe you need to configure it for global search https://nova.laravel.com/docs/4.0/search/global-search.html#custom-avatars-covers

Comment: i need select relation inside update/create field form, and i want see image, and name attribute, like avatar and name user

Comment: https://nova.laravel.com/docs/assets/img/belongs-to-search.0691f3de.png like this

Answer (score 1):

So we need use in child resource avatar field

Docs: If a resource contains an Avatar field, that field will be displayed next to the resource's title when the resource is displayed in search results.
https://nova.laravel.com/docs/4.0/resources/fields.html#avatar-field